# showColumns(n,n) previously worked but no longer works

Tags: google-apps-script

The script below has been working for a several years,but has very recently stopped working properly. I can't figure out why.

In my CLASSROLL sheet, the email column 14 is normally hidden.

The desired behaviour of this script is to show a column for a period of time then hide it again.
The actual behaviour is that script runs for the expected period the column doesnt show.

Diagnosistic action to date. 
-Running Debug shows nothing.
-Manually unhiding column 14 and then running the script shows that the hideColumns does work at the last stage of the script.

Can anyone help with this please? Why has it stopped working only recently?

```
function showEmails(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CLASSROLL");
    sheet.showColumns(14,1);  
    Utilities.sleep(20000);
    sheet.hideColumns(14,1);
}
```

Comment: How about putting `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after the line of `sheet.showColumns(14,1);`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: Wow! That worked thanks. BUT why has it only now become an issue after working without the SpreadsheetApp.flush()  for the last several years.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, unfortunately, I have no clear answer for it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. By the way, when your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: Script needed SpreadsheetApp.flush(); after the line  sheet.showColumns(14,1);

no explanation as to why this flush has become necessary only recently.